# PhpMyAdmin dá erro ao importar arquivo SQL mesmo após alterações no PHP.ini

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Recentemente instalei manualmente o **PHP**, **Apache** e o **MariaDB** no Ubuntu 20.04, tudo aparentemente funciona normal, consigo acessar e modificar os ***bancos de dados*** tanto pelo terminal quanto pelo **Workbench** ou **DBeaver**.

Meu problema é com o **PhpMyAdmin** pra importar os bancos de dados SQL, mesmo arquivos leves, já fiz todas as alterações no **php.ini**, já dei '**sudo chmod 777**' em todas as pastas **TMP** que o **PHP** ou o **PhpMyAdmin** utiliza e ainda aparece o erro:

> Não foram recebidos dados para importar. Ou não foi submetir um nome
> de ficheiro, ou o tamanho do ficheiro excede o tamanho máximo
> permitido pela sua configuração PHP. Veja FAQ 1.16.

Já desinstalei o PHP e suas bibliotecas....
Já alterei em **apache2/php.ini** e **cli/php.ini**

```
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir =/var/tmp
post_max_size = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 1024MB
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 500
memory_limit = 2048M
max_file_uploads = 30
post_max_size = 2048M
```

Não sei mais o que fazer, desconfio que aidna seja no PHP, quando desativo os serviços e mudo pro LAMPP do XAMPP funciona perfeito.

Comment: você está usando xampp?

Comment: No Xampp funciona de boa, o problema tá sendo no PHP mesmo, fiz uma pagina pra testar upload fica aparecendo a mensagem: 
"O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido na diretiva upload_max_filesize do php.ini."
sendo que já alterei  em apache2/php.ini e cli/php.ini

Comment: Já alterei também as permissões de /var/tmp, mas o erro UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE continua....

Comment: O problema está sendo só no PHP, fiz um arquivo básico de upload pra teste, quando uso o Lampp(Xampp) funciona de boa, quando alterno pro apache2 normal 'upload_max_filesize' sendo que está com  1024MB

Answer (score -3):

Quase surto sem encontrar o que não deixava fazer os Uploads, fiz várias alterações em **apache2/php.ini** e **cli/php.ini** e nada, cheguei criar um link simbólico do **cli/php.ini** para **apache2/php.ini** pra ficar alterando em apenas um arquivo.

Mas depois de alterar de:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1024MB
```

para:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1048576
```

resolvido!!!  :)